# Venturi effect better for cooling through duct

Tags: air, flow, cooling

I have a laptop which is overheating, and I would like to improve the cooling (without opening the laptop).

The only option I can see (reasonably) is to increase the airflow moving through the laptop.  There is an intake port, and exhaust port, for air.  And air is moved through the laptop by an internal fan.

I thought of using an external fan to suck air out the exhaust port (building a small cardboard adapter to fit snugly over the exhaust port).  This should increase the volume of air moving through the laptop (and past the internal heatsink).

However, someone told me that I should use the 'venturi effect' and I will get a lot better cooling.  I understand the basics of the venture effect, but I don't understand how that would apply in this case.  Can someone explain what I should do to benefit from the venturi effect, and why that would be more efficient than just adding suction to the exhaust port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Venturi effect](https://www.comsol.com/blogs/exploring-the-venturi-effect/) accelerates airflow and reduces pressure within a properly designed constricted passage.  It will not result in moving greater quantities of air through your computer.  It affects only the constricted passage.

The only way to increase the amount of airflow through your computer is to apply greater mechanical energy (greater fan speed).  The venturi effect is useful for accelerating airflow and creating lower pressure within the constricted passage.  But the Venturi effect alone will not force more air per unit time through your computer, so there will be no effect on heat transferred away from your CPU.  If you were able to increase the volume of air flowing per unit time solely by constricting the passage, that would violate conservation of mechanical energy.